# Fastest MySQL Storage Engine for `Select` queries

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, myisam

I am having a question about "which storage device to choose" for my database tables. I have a table with 28 million records. I will insert data after creating the table, after that, no `insert` - `update` -`delete` operation will take place. Never. Only `select` operations.

I have a query like below

```
SELECT `indexVal`, COUNT(`indexVal`) FROM `key_word` WHERE `hashed_word` IN ('001','01v','0ji','0k9','0vc','0@v','0%d','13#' ,'148' ,'1e1','1sx','1v$','1@c','1?b','1?k','226','2kl','2ue','2*l','2?4','36h','3au','3us','4d~') GROUP BY `indexVal`
```

This counts how many number of times a particular result appeared in search. In `InnoDB`, this operation took 5 seconds. This is too much, because my orifginal dataset will be in billions.

To do this kind of work, which MySQL storage you recommend?

Comment: Which indexes are defined on the table? What is the execution plan?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Hi, I will have indexes as defined in below SO user "Thilows" 's answer.

Comment: Is this a flat table (does it have relations with other tables)? If its flat, then the fastest way would be to store it in a cache.  If you will only execute one type of query, and your data set is _very large_, then you need to consider an alternative solution with map/reduce; like couchdb which would be a lot faster.

Comment: If you don't ever update that table, why not store the result of the aggregation in a new table after you inserted everything into the `key_word` table?

Comment: Also check out this: [MyISAM versus InnoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148/myisam-versus-innodb)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Could you elaborate on the aggregation idea? I'm not sure how a "pre aggregation" would work when the condition is on hashed_word and the grouping is on indexVal. Changing the list of hashed words would affect the values per indexVal, so I can't see a _great_ way to pre calculate. Do you mean some sort of pre calculated hashed_value count per indexVal so you could use `sum` to aggregate instead of count?

Answer (score 0):

More than the storage engine, having the proper index in place seems important.

In your case, `CREATE INDEX idx_1 ON key_word (index_val, hashed_word)` should help.

And if the data truly never changes, you could even pre-compute and cache some of those results.

For example

```
 CREATE TABLE counts  AS SELECT index_val, hashed_word, count(index_val) 
 FROM key_word
 GROUP BY index_val, hashed_word
```

Comment: Wouldn't be `hashed_word, index_val` better? (Although I'm not sure MySQL can use an index for an `OR` condition like that)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Inside my query, I already use `OR` condition inside the `IN` clause right? Sorry I am not good with SQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Maybe. I'm also worried if MySQL can handle the OR, so I put index_val first.  Only one way to tell: measure both.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: The index I have is `ALTER TABLE key_word ADD INDEX (hashed_word, indexVal)`

Comment: @Thilo: Yes, the data never change. if do, we can rebuild the tables.

Comment: @Dongle: Try both indexes, and get execution plans. See which one works better.

Comment: @Thilo: `hashed_word, index_val` is better, but it takes 5 seconds. that is slow.

Comment: Try pre-computed aggregates then.

Comment: @Thilo: Your new table generated results only with 1 in "count" column.

Answer (score 0):

For SELECT-only queries, ARCHIVE is the fastest storage engine. 
As it is MyISAM-based, and the following advice is for MyISAM as well, don't use varchar but fixed-size char columns, and you will get better performance.
Sure, even faster if it's the data is loaded in memory, instead read from disk.

Comment: ARCHIVE engine is a bad way to store rows for selecting... All rows are compressed and SELECT query will be slow.